# dispatch_once what means "Always call this function before using or testing any variables that are initialized by the block." in documentation?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Apple documentation [1]
https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once
in "Discussion" section says:

> This function is useful for initialization of global data (singletons)
>   in an application. **Always call this function before using or testing
>   any variables that are initialized by the block.**
>
> If called simultaneously from multiple threads, this function waits
>   synchronously until the block has completed.
>
> The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static
>   scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic
>   storage (including Objective-C instance variables) is undefined.

What does following phrase means?

> Always call this function before using or testing
>   any variables that are initialized by the block.

Could you kindly show short example of code when I must comply with this requirement?

My thoughts:
this NOT about block like in following example:

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

because of I can not (for sure) use `sharedInstance` initialized by block before call to `dispatch_once`. Because `dispatch_once` calling this block! So what is the block, that Apple documentation warns us about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that if you initialize `sharedInstance` inside the block passed to `dispatch_once`, you need to make sure that `dispatch_once` is called prior to accessing `sharedInstance` for the first time. In other words, if you access any variable that is set for the first time by `dispatch_once`, the value that you read may be uninitialized.

Comment: Minor refinement: You say "prior to accessing `sharedInstance` for the first time" ... No, I think the idea is that you should _always_ call `dispatch_once`, not just the first time, before using that `sharedInstance` local static, just like his code sample does, because you don't reliably know from where it will be called first.

Comment: Thank you very much @dasblinkenlight!

Comment: Answer and @Rob comment make situation quite clear. Really just because "value that you read may be uninitialized" then we must "always call dispatch_once, not just the first time". "Always call" guarantees initialization for us.